# Correcting a git mistake - used cp instead git mv

Tags: git, merge, duplicates

I stupidly created some new directories and copied some files there from within the repository. These files had already been modified in their original location - several commits/pushes. Then I started to modify the “new” copied-over files - several commits/pushes. Is there a way to merge the changes made to the files in their original location with the ones that have been modified at the new location, so that the “new” ones have all commit history (including commits made at their original location), and then optionally remove the “old” ones?

I know I messed it up, any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git can help you.

Here is your file structure:

```
repository/
  .git/
  somefile.txt

not-a-repository/
  somefile.txt
```

Now initiate a merge:

1. Go into `repository`, make your working directory clean (by committing or stashing any due change)
2. Checkout the last commit where the two versions matched (when you cp'd the file):
   `git checkout deadbeef`
3. Create a working branch:
   `git checkout -b feature/merge-duplicated-file`
4. Get your file's latest version:
   `cp ../not-a-repository/somefile.txt ./somefile.txt`
   `git add ./somefile.txt && git commit -m "merge of somefile.txt preparation"`
5. Merge:
   `git checkout develop`
   `git merge --no-ff feature/merge-duplicated-file`
   -- Handle the conflicts manually --
   `git commit`

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, here are my assumptions:

- You have a linear commit history (i.e. there are no branches or diverging commits).
- You have two files in your working directory and wish to merge those two files while conserving their commit history.

To me, this sounds like an interactive rebase would do the trick. I would personally recommend you to do this in a GUI like GitKraken, SourceTree or Git Extensions as you'll be able to see exactly what is happening, but you can also do everything on the command line.

1. Create a backup branch at your current commit that you can come back to in case you mess up again: `git branch temp`
2. Find the hash of the commit before you did your mistake, e.g. using `git log`.
3. Start an interactive rebase on that commit using `git -c rebase.autoSquash=false rebase -i --no-autosquash "a775cf45a0163b82e9d4ffcc24955b09bf150cf3"` where you replace my hash with the hash you got.
4. Git will open a text editor with a text file where you will be able to choose what to do with each commit. In that text file, keep everything as it is, but replace the word `pick` with the word `edit` for every commit where one of the affected files was edited.
5. Save the file and close the text editor. Git will now begin the actual rebase. When it reaches one of the commits you marked with "edit", git will halt and give you the opportunity to fix this commit. In your case, this is the opportunity to merge those files manually. Once you are done, run `git add .` followed by `git commit --amend` Git will open your text editor again to give you the possibility to modify the commit message. Close the text editor and run `git rebase --continue`. Git will now resume the rebase process. This will repeat until all your commits are rebased.

If you (and you most certainly will) encounter merge conflicts, use your preferred text editor or IDE to fix them and run `git rebase --continue` once they are fixed.

In case you did something wrong during this process, you can always abort the rebase by running `git rebase --abort` which should restore everything to the state before you started the rebase. However, even if it fails to restore that, you can still revert to the `temp` branch created earlier like so:

```
git reset --hard "temp"
```

As always, when you're rewriting history, make sure that you
a) have not pushed the broken history to anywhere yet or
b) you did your mess-up on a feature branch where people are expecting force-pushes or
c) you informed relevant coworkers/contributors of what you're doing.

**Edit:** If modifying history safely is not an option (e.g. modifying commits on master is in most cases a terrible idea), you should rather do a merge as suggested in the other answer.